# Android Application not working when notification from gps is received frequently

Tags: android

****Please have a look at the below written source code lines and suggest:***-*

**In the below mentioned code lines I am trying to request for GPS and Network location in every 60 seconds.**

```
if (gps_enabled)
{
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0,       locationListenerGps);
}

if (network_enabled)
{
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 0,
                    locationListenerNetwork);
}
```

**Below mentioned is the code for location change listeners:-**

```
LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener()
{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
        mCurrentGpsLocation = location;

        String userCurrentGpsLocation = findUserAddress(mCurrentGpsLocation, mPreviousGpsLocation);

        mPreviousGpsLocation = location;

        for(int i = 0, size = mLocationUpdateListeners.size(); i<size; i++)
        {
            LocationUpdateListener listener = mLocationUpdateListeners.get(i);

            listener.recieveGpsNotification(userCurrentGpsLocation);
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};

LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener()
{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mCurrentNetworkLocation = location;

        String userCurrentNetworkLocation =findUserAddress(mCurrentNetworkLocation, mPreviousNetworkLocation);

        mPreviousNetworkLocation = location;

        for(int i = 0, size = mLocationUpdateListeners.size(); i<size; i++)
        {
            LocationUpdateListener listener = mLocationUpdateListeners.get(i);

            listener.recieveNetworkNotification(userCurrentNetworkLocation);
        }
        }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};
```

**And on receiving location change event for GPS and Network, I simply call my listeners recieveGpsNotification() and recieveNetworkNotification() methods respectively.
Logic of recieveGpsNotification() are as follows :-**

```
public void recieveGpsNotification(String gpsLocation)
{
    sendEmail();
}
```

**Problems :-

1) I expect call to sendMail() should come after every 60 sec but I am receiving notifications very frequently and after 4-5 notifications my application crashes. Please help if you see any error in implementation logic.

2) Will i also receive notifications for GPS even when my activity is in pause state or in stopped state, because i want to receive notification even when my activity is in background or it is stopped?

Additional Query :-
Whenever android framework provides us with GPS location updates, every time notification come through a different thread or is it the thread that request for notifications? 
Thanks in Advance.
**

Comment: Can you post your crash log?

Comment: hello JoeyG, I am only getting error message "My application has stopped working". I am using eclipse for my application development and I am not running this application on emulator, i am using my own phone for testing this app. Where can i find logs generated?

Comment: You need the LogCat view to view the error logs. In Eclipse, Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android -> LogCat. The tab will show up in the window at the bottom of the screen with your other open views.

As for the rate of the notifications, I am unsure why it is crashing, but if you want to control the exact delivery rate, you will need to implement a timer yourself.
When the application pauses, you need to unregister the GPS sensors notifications in onPause(). Finally, you probably only want to use GPS or the Network, not both.

Comment: is it possible that you are calling requestLocationUpdates several times ?

Comment: As an aside (not addressing your problem), with your conditionals, won't you only get network updates if network updates are enabled?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding a min distance to each update. Also consider grouping the updates together for your sendEmail() method
2. Move your Location Listener logic into a Service that runs in the background. This will keep the updates coming. However, be aware that GPS updates are awful for battery life and users will not be happy to see GPS trying to get a lock all the time.
3. I believe those updates happen on the thread in which they are declared. So you should move your findUserAddress() method and other complex operations to a different thread.
4. Also, You should only use one method to get GPS updates. The normal use case is to try GPS Adapter, if not enabled or preset, fall through to use the Network listener. Since you have both you will be getting both updates on different intervals.

Comment: What if user stays still at a location and does not move. If i add min distance for each update, Will i receive notification even if user does not move.

Comment: No in that case you won't. Also updating answer to reflect using only one location listener.